# PHP query on loop slowly

Tags: php, oracle

I'm using `for` loop on my PHP code. Then I put `select` query there.

```
SELECT * FROM MEP_TBL_OUTPUT_DETAILS WHERE MODELID_FK = '" . $dModel['MODELID'] . "' AND RUNNING_DATE = TO_DATE('$logDate', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND TS_CODE = '" . $dDtl['TS_CODE_DESCRIPTION'] . "' AND SHIFT = 'Morning' AND QUANTITY_STATUS = 'OK' AND CONFIGURATIONID_FK = '" . $dDtl['CONFIGURATIONID'] . "'
```

And the full PHP code including the loop is:

```
for($i = $readRowAfter; $i < count($linesAccept); $i++)
{
    $dateobjAccept = DateTime::createFromFormat($createFromFormat, $linesAccept[$i]);

    if($dateobjAccept < $toDateTime && $dateobjAccept > $fromDateTime)
    {
        $rowsintimespanAccept++;

        $logDate = $dateobjAccept->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $logDateInsert = $dateobjAccept->format('d-M-Y H:i:s');

        $qChk = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM MEP_TBL_OUTPUT_DETAILS WHERE MODELID_FK = '" . $dModel['MODELID'] . "' AND RUNNING_DATE = TO_DATE('$logDate', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND TS_CODE = '" . $dDtl['TS_CODE_DESCRIPTION'] . "' AND SHIFT = 'Morning' AND QUANTITY_STATUS = 'OK' AND CONFIGURATIONID_FK = '" . $dDtl['CONFIGURATIONID'] . "'");
        oci_execute($qChk);
        if(oci_fetch($qChk) > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            \\Insert Query
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
count($linesAccept) sometimes can be 2000 more.
```

Then when I try to run the code, it will go slowly on query.

My question is there any possible way to do fast query?

*My suspect is on query.

Comment: The query looks simple and should not be slow since is a simple select. How much doest it take to execute 1 single run??

Comment: What have you tried to spot the error? What makes you think that executing the SQL query is the culprit? Do you use any indices on your table?

Comment: I'm no PHP programmer, but it doesn't look like you're binding the variables into the sql statement, so Oracle will have to do a hard parse for every time you run the SQL. That's not good practice - you should bind variables. Also, you could use a single merge statement to insert the data if there isn't already a match, rather than querying for the data and inserting only if it's not found. Finally, do you need the loop, or can you create a single SQL statement that will load all the data you need in one go?

Comment: @Boneist Yes I need the query is on loop not a single query statement. Any idea?

Comment: I’ve already given you two things to try! Bind your variables and use a merge statement!